# Difference between at least and within!

Tags: grammaticality, differences, sentence, syntactic-analysis

*The index shall switch from the previous index to the new index within the next 2 meters after moving into a new road.*

**Vs.**

*The system shall update the index at least 2 meters after entering a new road.*

Is there a difference between the information that these 2 sentences convey?

Comment: Neither sentence is particularly clear or idiomatic. They sound like poor translations.

Comment: @Greybeard - What exactly is missing? Can you please point the possibly missing bits?

Comment: I did not say that anything was missing. It would help if you gave some background to the question, e.g. What are you talking about? Where would the examples appear? What is the purpose of the examples?

Answer (score 0):

They are diametrically opposed, completely different.

The first mandates a maximum length in which to make the change (within two metres: it must be less); the second a minimum (at least two metres: it could be more).

*At least* gives the least possible value. *Within* gives the furthest boundary.

> **At least**
>   Not less than; at the minimum.
>
> **within**
>   Inside the range of (an area or boundary)
>
> (both Lexico)